# Lexicographic sorting algorithm for n items labeled with R,V,B

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, sorting

Let *A* be an array *A[0..n-1]*.

The array has *n* items.

**Each item** is labeled with **one** of these letters: *{R,V,B}*.

For example, *A[0].label=V*, *A[1].label=R*, etc.

What is the **best algorithm for sorting items of A in lexicographic order**? What is its time **complexity**?

I don't know if I could apply **counting sort**, because each element is in a range *[0..k]* with *k=2*, supposing that we can give an integer value to each letter (*B=0*, *R=1*, *V=2*).

Comment: Use counting sort.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus so is my intuition correct? If yes, I assume that cost d*(n+k), where d=tuple dimension, should be 1*(n+2)=O(n) in this case.